# How to change the indicator in rich InputNumberSlider?

Tags: css, richfaces

I know that inputNumberSlider in richfaces allow you to increase values with a slider also by an indicator. Is it possible to change the indicator with an other shape, for example square or circle?.

I saw that there are many properties to change aspect, like, for example, several style properties to change colors,width, to handling input, steps and other, but I didn't find anything about this.
Here are some examples:

```
<rich:inputNumberSlider value="50" showInput="false" enableManualInput="false" showBoundaryValues="false" showTooltip="false"/>
```

Without boundary values and without manual input

```
<rich:inputNumberSlider maxValue="100" step="2" value="0" width="6" showArrows="true" showTooltip="false" />
```

A disabled inputNumberSlider example:

```
<rich:inputNumberSlider  width="100" maxValue="200" step="1" showArrows="true" showTooltip="false" disabled="true" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon is not directly customizable but you can use [handleClass](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/rich/inputNumberSlider.html#handleClass):

```
.myHandleClass {
    background-image: url('my/image.gif');
}

<rich:inputNumberSlider handleClass="myHandleClass" … />
```